# AWS Amplify UI - "Failed to get the signed in user" after entering confirmation code

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm having an issue with the Amplify Cognito UI not moving onto the next stage when I confirm a sign up.  This is happening when running locally, I haven't tried it live yet.

The rest of the UI works correctly (when you sign up, it moves to the "enter your confirmation code" dialog, and I can sign in correctly with an existing user), but when I enter my code and click confirm I get the following error in the console and it stays on the same screen.

```
AuthClass - Failed to get the signed in user – "No current user"
```

[image]

However, looking at the Cognito console, the user has been changed to CONFIRMED state so I know it's working.

I am using the amplify manually (i.e. I am not using any of the CLI elements, or the backend, and I am hooking it into an existing Cognito user pool).

Here's what I have as my AWS config (as mentioned, hand rolled, with some ID's masked)

```
const awsConfig = {
    Auth: {
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        userPoolId: 'eu-west-1_xxxxxxx',
        userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        mandatorySignIn: true,

        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',

        oauth: {
            scope: ['email', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
            redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            responseType: 'code',
        },
    },
};
```

In my component ts file, I've pretty much followed their example

```
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    user: CognitoUserInterface | undefined;
    authState: AuthState | undefined;

    signUpFormFields: FormFieldTypes;

    constructor(private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.signUpFormFields = [
            {
                type: 'email',
                label: 'Email Address',
                placeholder: 'you@email.com',
                required: true,
            },
            {
                type: 'given_name',
                label: 'First Name',
                placeholder: '',
                required: true,
            },
            {
                type: 'family_name',
                label: 'Last Name',
                placeholder: '',
                required: true,
            },
            {
                type: 'password',
                label: 'Password',
                placeholder: '',
                required: true,
            },
        ];

        onAuthUIStateChange((newAuthState) => {
            console.log(newAuthState);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        onAuthUIStateChange((authState, authData) => {
            this.authState = authState;
            this.user = authData as CognitoUserInterface;
            this._ref.detectChanges();
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): (authStateHandler: AuthStateHandler) => () => void {
        return onAuthUIStateChange;
    }

}
```

And the same with the HTML elements

```
<amplify-authenticator *ngIf="authState !== 'signedin'" usernameAlias="email">
    <amplify-sign-up slot="sign-up" usernameAlias="email" [formFields]="signUpFormFields"></amplify-sign-up>
    <amplify-sign-in slot="sign-in" usernameAlias="email"></amplify-sign-in>
</amplify-authenticator>

<div *ngIf="authState === 'signedin' && user" class="App">
    <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
    <div>Hello, {{user.username}}</div>
    <!-- This is where you application template code goes -->
</div>
```

I'm not sure what should actually happen here, should it go to the logged in screen as per the [Cognito examples here](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/q/framework/angular) or should it go to the sign in screen.  The docs are not very clear on the expected flow.

But I do know it shouldn't stay on that screen with an error in the console!

Is anyone aware of what I am doing wrong here, or what I need to do to kick the UI onto the next part of the process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. It was because I applied a Lambda trigger to the post-confirmation signup.

If you are using a post-confirmation trigger, that lambda function must return the unaltered event.